# php only get the first occurrence of a word from an array

Tags: php, regex, dynamic-data, strstr

I have an array of tags that I'm pulling from a database, I am exporting the tags out into a tag cloud. I'm stuck on getting only the first instance of the word. For example:

```
$string = "test,test,tag,tag2,tag3";

$getTags = explode("," , $string);
  foreach ($getTags as $tag ){
     echo($tag);
   }
```

This would output the test tag twice. at first i thought i could use `stristr` to do something like:

```
  foreach ($getTags as $tag ){
      $tag= stristr($tag , $tag); 
        echo($tag);
   }
```

This is obviously silly logic and doesn't work, `stristr` seems to only replace the first occurrence so something like "test 123" would only get rid of the "test" and would return "123" I've seen this can also be done with regex but I haven't found a dynamic exmaple of that.

Thanks,
Brooke

**Edit:** `unique_array()` works if I'm using a static string but won't work with the data from the database because I'm using a while loop to get each rows data.

```
    $getTag_data = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM `news_data`");
if ($getTag_data)
{

   while ($rowTags = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTag_data))
   {
     $getTags = array_unique(explode("," , $rowTags['tags']));
        foreach ($getTags as $tag ){
        echo ($tag);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that each row in your table contains more than one tag, separated by coma, like this:

```
Row0: php, regex, stackoverflow
Row1: php, variables, scope
Row2: c#, regex
```

If that's the case, try this:

```
$getTag_data = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM `news_data`");

//fetch all the tags you found and place it into an array (with duplicated entries)
$getTags = array();
if ($getTag_data) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTag_data)) {
     array_merge($getTags, explode("," , $row['tags']);
   }
}

//clean up duplicity
$getTags = array_unique($getTags);

//display
foreach ($getTags as $tag ) {
   echo ($tag);
}
```

I'd point out that this is not efficient.

Another option (already mentioned here) would be to use the tags as array keys, with the advantage of being able to count them easily.
You could do it like this:

```
$getTag_data = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM `news_data`");

$getTags = array();
if ($getTag_data) {
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTag_data)) {
     $tags = explode("," , $row['tags']);
     foreach($tags as $t) {
       $getTags[$t] = isset($getTags[$t]) ? $getTags[$t]+1 : 1;
     }
   }
}

//display
foreach ($getTags as $tag => $count) {
   echo "$tag ($count times)";
}
```

- please keep in mind none of this code was tested, it's just so you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had to add `$t = trim($t);` inside the foreach loop that was setting the keys as "test" was different from " test". Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

use `array_unique()`

```
$string = "test,test,tag,tag2,tag3";

$getTags = array_unique(explode("," , $string));
foreach ($getTags as $tag ){
   echo($tag);
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work from reading the php manual. It works if if I'm using a static string but not if I pull the data from a MySQL database. I think this might be because I'm pulling from multiple rows and exploding each row.

Answer (score 2):

Use your words as keys to the dictionary, not as values.

```
$allWords=array()
foreach(explode("," , $string) as $word)
  $allWords[$word]=true;
//now you can extract these keys to a regular array if you want to
$allWords=array_keys($allWords);
```

While you are at it, you can also count them!

```
$wordCounters=array()
foreach(explode("," , $string) as $word)
{
  if (array_key_exists($word,$wordCounters))
     $wordCounters[$word]++;
  else
     $wordCounters=1;
}

//word list:
$wordList=array_keys($wordCounters);

//counter for some word:
echo $wordCounters['test'];
```

Comment: This is the winner, IMO. Should be the fastest, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe php's array_unique is what you are looking for:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function before iterating over the array? It removes every duplicate string and return the unique functions.